# Elements are moved after exporting SVG in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I'm trying to export a SVG that contains two elements: a circle shape and a text.
In Sketch, everything seems fine:

[image]

But when I click the <kbd>Export Selected...</kbd> button, it's exported like this:

[image]

Why is that happening?

Comment: Hard to guess what is going wrong. Only thing I can think of is some problem with the font. Is the D a text object? If it is, does it help to expand it into a regular path?

Comment: When I use "text to path", the text is rotated and moved to a random position...

Comment: OK, so it *is* a text object? That could be the root of the problem. The SVG will then depend on the font file. Probably a bad idea. You could just rotate the D and reposition and the problem is solved. Does the same problems (D shifted in SVG and D rotates and moves when expanding) occur with another font like Arial?

Comment: I can't move the text when it's set 'to path' because it moves all over the place in different directions, pretty weird. This also happens with other fonts, like Arial.

Comment: I have no experience with Sketch, but that sounds like buggy behavior which should be reported to the developer. Can you remove and reinstall Sketch or is it an online application? Then perhaps try another browser? I don't think we can help with this.

Comment: Yes I'm gonna try that. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up exporting as pdf and converting it to svg using this online tool: https://cloudconvert.com/pdf-to-svg